# Track push receive with Firebase analytics

Tags: push-notification, firebase-analytics

We are sending push notification through Firebase to iOS and Android users. Can I track with Firebase analytics the received push on iOS and Android including if the app was not open in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, following [automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) let Firebase collect Notification based events in the Analytics reports.

notification_dismiss
notification_foreground

notification_open
notification_receive